# google maps directions return to origin

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm trying to get routes of `origin -> waypoint -> destination`
Everything works well except of one specific request:

> **Origin (Point A) :** PH Benidor, Calle Gaspar O. Hernández, Panamá
>   **Waypoint (Point B):** BAC Credomatic | Sucursal Plaza New York, Calle 50, Panamá
>   **Destination (Point A):** PH Benidor, Calle Gaspar O. Hernández, Panamá

So if I make request from `A -> B` - everything works fine, making `B -> A` works also. `A -> A` works as well. As soon as I do a waypoint for that specific (B) address, google API returns **ZERO_RESULT**.

Check URL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=<API_KEY>&mode=driving&origin=PH+Benidor%2C+Calle+Gaspar+O.+Hern%C3%A1ndez%2C+Panam%C3%A1&destination=PH+Benidor%2C+Calle+Gaspar+O.+Hern%C3%A1ndez%2C+Panam%C3%A1&alternatives=true&units=metric&waypoints=BAC+Credomatic+|+Sucursal+Plaza+New+York%2C+Calle+50%2C+Panam%C3%A1`

**UPDATE**
Addresses are taken from Google Autocomplete API field, so I assume they are correctly formatted. Route from `A -> B` works well with same addresses
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=API_KEY&alternatives=true&units=metric&mode=driving&origin=PH+Benidor%2C+Calle+Gaspar+O.+Hern%C3%A1ndez%2C+Panam%C3%A1&destination=BAC+Credomatic+|+Sucursal+Plaza+New+York%2C+Calle+50%2C+Panam%C3%A1`

*Response*

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJxX3EIvqorI8RRhwI3jYajZc",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJMR2dd-OorI8ROKhRZctCf0k",
         "types" : [
            "bus_station",
            "establishment",
            "point_of_interest",
            "transit_station"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 8.9896817,
               "lng" : -79.52026149999999
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 8.979656199999999,
               "lng" : -79.52709229999999
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Картографические данные © 2017 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "2,1 км",
                  "value" : 2052
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "8 мин.",
                  "value" : 480
               },
               "end_address" : "Calle 50, Panamá, Панама",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 8.982186499999999,
                  "lng" : -79.52026149999999
               },
               "start_address" : "PH Benidor, Calle Gaspar O. Hernández, Panamá, Панама",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 8.9896817,
                  "lng" : -79.5251863
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,1 км",
                        "value" : 111
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 50
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9887005,
                        "lng" : -79.52522759999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Направляйтесь на \u003cb\u003eюг\u003c/b\u003e по \u003cb\u003eCalle Gaspar O. Hernández\u003c/b\u003e в сторону \u003cb\u003eVía Argentina\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "oxzu@lgkdNbDR^K"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9896817,
                        "lng" : -79.5251863
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,2 км",
                        "value" : 241
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 мин.",
                        "value" : 99
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.987735199999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52327099999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eVía Argentina\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "krzu@tgkdNDKr@wBLc@N[b@kAr@}AHQBE@A"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9887005,
                        "lng" : -79.52522759999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,7 км",
                        "value" : 737
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 мин.",
                        "value" : 128
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.982404600000001,
                        "lng" : -79.52709229999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eнаправо\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eVía España\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "klzu@l{jdNf@Hl@Nb@Ld@Lj@Xn@`@z@t@Zd@JRHJT\\PVPPNNVNj@^\\P`FzCh@VhAp@j@p@@@pCxA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.987735199999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52327099999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,4 км",
                        "value" : 424
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 мин.",
                        "value" : 105
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.979656199999999,
                        "lng" : -79.5244422
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eCalle Aquilino de la Guardia\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "_kyu@hskdNBE@ADE`CcDp@w@d@i@j@e@xBeBd@[~@s@p@a@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.982404600000001,
                        "lng" : -79.52709229999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,5 км",
                        "value" : 539
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 мин.",
                        "value" : 98
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.982186499999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52026149999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eCalle 50\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eCalle Nicanor de Obarrio\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eПункт назначения будет справа\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "{yxu@vbkdNkAcCmAgCOWm@kACECCg@gAm@aA}CcGe@{@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.979656199999999,
                        "lng" : -79.5244422
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "oxzu@lgkdNbDR^KDK`A{Cr@gB|@oBDGtAXhAZj@Xn@`@z@t@Zd@T^f@t@`@`@bAn@~FlDrBhAl@r@pCxABEFGrD{EpAoA~CaC~@s@p@a@yCkGeAmBuAiCcE_I"
         },
         "summary" : "Vía España и Calle 50/Calle Nicanor de Obarrio",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      },
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 8.9896817,
               "lng" : -79.52026149999999
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 8.9806346,
               "lng" : -79.52528719999999
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Картографические данные © 2017 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "2,1 км",
                  "value" : 2149
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "10 мин.",
                  "value" : 588
               },
               "end_address" : "Calle 50, Panamá, Панама",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 8.982186499999999,
                  "lng" : -79.52026149999999
               },
               "start_address" : "PH Benidor, Calle Gaspar O. Hernández, Panamá, Панама",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 8.9896817,
                  "lng" : -79.5251863
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,1 км",
                        "value" : 111
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 50
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9887005,
                        "lng" : -79.52522759999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Направляйтесь на \u003cb\u003eюг\u003c/b\u003e по \u003cb\u003eCalle Gaspar O. Hernández\u003c/b\u003e в сторону \u003cb\u003eVía Argentina\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "oxzu@lgkdNbDR^K"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9896817,
                        "lng" : -79.5251863
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,2 км",
                        "value" : 241
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 мин.",
                        "value" : 99
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.987735199999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52327099999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eVía Argentina\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "krzu@tgkdNDKr@wBLc@N[b@kAr@}AHQBE@A"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9887005,
                        "lng" : -79.52522759999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,2 км",
                        "value" : 238
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 43
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.985976599999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52439769999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eнаправо\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eVía España\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "klzu@l{jdNf@Hl@Nb@Ld@Lj@Xn@`@z@t@Zd@JR"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.987735199999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52327099999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,2 км",
                        "value" : 231
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 59
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9846278,
                        "lng" : -79.5227939
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eCalle 52 Este\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "kazu@nbkdNFGR]pF{G"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.985976599999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52439769999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,1 км",
                        "value" : 149
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 62
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9853383,
                        "lng" : -79.52164499999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eAv. Samuel Lewis\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "}xyu@lxjdNWe@MSMQyAyC"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9846278,
                        "lng" : -79.5227939
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,2 км",
                        "value" : 183
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 41
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9839468,
                        "lng" : -79.52075069999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eнаправо\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eCalle 54 Este\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "k}yu@fqjdNpGmDBC"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9853383,
                        "lng" : -79.52164499999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,3 км",
                        "value" : 332
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 74
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.982836499999999,
                        "lng" : -79.5233909
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eнаправо\u003c/b\u003e на перекрестке 1 на \u003cb\u003eAv. Ricardo Arango\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "utyu@tkjdNzAlC@@rCvESfD"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9839468,
                        "lng" : -79.52075069999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "88 м",
                        "value" : 88
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 19
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.982181299999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52383399999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eAvenida Ricardo Arango\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "wmyu@d|jdNbCvA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.982836499999999,
                        "lng" : -79.5233909
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,2 км",
                        "value" : 197
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 58
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9806346,
                        "lng" : -79.523155
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eCalle Beatriz M. de Cabal\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "siyu@|~jdN~BoB~AS`AAJ?F?"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.982181299999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52383399999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "61 м",
                        "value" : 61
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 26
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9809009,
                        "lng" : -79.52267329999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e в сторону \u003cb\u003eCalle 50\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eCalle Nicanor de Obarrio\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "}_yu@vzjdNMYg@gA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9806346,
                        "lng" : -79.523155
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "19 м",
                        "value" : 19
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 7
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9807585,
                        "lng" : -79.52257179999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eнаправо\u003c/b\u003e в сторону \u003cb\u003eCalle 50\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eCalle Nicanor de Obarrio\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "sayu@twjdNZQ?A"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9809009,
                        "lng" : -79.52267329999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,3 км",
                        "value" : 299
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 мин.",
                        "value" : 50
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.982186499999999,
                        "lng" : -79.52026149999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Поверните \u003cb\u003eналево\u003c/b\u003e на \u003cb\u003eCalle 50\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eCalle Nicanor de Obarrio\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eПункт назначения будет справа\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "w`yu@`wjdNCCg@gAm@aA}CcGe@{@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 8.9807585,
                        "lng" : -79.52257179999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "oxzu@lgkdNbDR^KDK`A{Cr@gB|@oBDGtAXhAZj@Xn@`@z@t@Zd@JRFGdGyHe@y@MQyAyCtGqD|AnCrCvESfDbCvA~BoB~AS`AAR?u@aBZSk@kAkEeIe@{@"
         },
         "summary" : "Av. Ricardo Arango",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

So I assume that something wrong with the address if it is in `waypoints` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the Directions API request with origin, destination and waypoints from your question

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=PH%20Benidor%2C%20Calle%20Gaspar%20O.%20Hern%C3%A1ndez%2C%20Panam%C3%A1&destination=PH%20Benidor%2C%20Calle%20Gaspar%20O.%20Hern%C3%A1ndez%2C%20Panam%C3%A1&mode=driving&waypoints=BAC%20Credomatic%7CSucursal%20Plaza%20New%20York%2C%20Calle%2050%2C%20Panam%C3%A1&key=MY_API_KEY`

The response contains following geocoded waypoints:

```
"geocoded_waypoints":[
{
  "geocoder_status":"OK",
  "place_id":"ChIJxX3EIvqorI8RRhwI3jYajZc",
  "types":[
    "premise"
  ]
},
{
  "geocoder_status":"OK",
  "place_id":"ChIJZ1RH5IDoaY8RcqGCRNAAPQw",
  "types":[
    "establishment","finance","point_of_interest"
  ]
},
{
  "geocoder_status":"OK",
  "place_id":"ChIJf1seg-OorI8R_66YzaG7hko",
  "types":[
    "bank","establishment","finance","food","point_of_interest","restaurant"
  ]
},
{
  "geocoder_status":"OK",
  "place_id":"ChIJxX3EIvqorI8RRhwI3jYajZc",
  "types":[
    "premise"
  ]
}]
```

Let's have a look at waypoint with place ID ChIJZ1RH5IDoaY8RcqGCRNAAPQw. It corresponds to the 'BAC Credomatic' in your request. If you check the place ID with geocoder tool, you will see that the 'BAC Credomatic' is resolved to business location in Honduras that located in island and cannot be reached by car.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJZ1RH5IDoaY8RcqGCRNAAPQw

[image]

This is a reason for ZERO_RESULTS. You must be more precise when specify addresses of waypoints. Have a look at the following document that explains how to format address strings properly:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it still not clear about: 1. why it works without waypoint (simple `A -> B`)? 2. all addresses I put in query I'm getting from **Google Autocomplete** field so I assume they are already normalized.

Comment: If you use place autocomplete it's strongly recommended to use place ID instead of the formatted texts. With place IDs you will get better results. Have a look at [best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices) for more details. Also, you can check this example that uses place IDs to get directions. In this example, there are only origin and destination, but you can implement waypoints as well: http://jsbin.com/xuyisem/1/edit?html,output